# use wordpress functions outside of wordpress folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script outside wordpress directory where I need to check if the user is currently logged in as admin.

Website structure is:

> /home/myscript.php 
>   /home/wordpress/check_if_admin.php

`check_if_admin.php` content is:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
//usually admin user id is 1 if its not working check admin user id from wp_users table
if($user_id == 1) {
  $admin = "1";
}

$is_admin = current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
  $admin = "1";
}
if (!empty($_GET['debug'])) {
  echo "UID $user_id / ADM $admin";
}
```

If I run the script from `/home/wordpress/check_if_admin.php` it works.
But if I try to include `check_if_admin.php` inside `myscript.php`, it doesn't work and the `$user_id / $admin` is always zero.

How can I check the admin status in `myscript.php` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding with absolute path.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: `$user_id = $current_user->ID;` it only work when you logged in.

Comment: i am logged in. The script is returning 1 if ran from wordpress folder, but as soon as i put the script outside of the wordpress folder, it returns zero

Comment: i have tested your code with `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');` it is working fine

Comment: can you please add both relative path when adding in wordpress folder or out of the folder ?

Comment: i also tried that but it doesn't change anything. The file is already correctly included, but it always returns zero. It's probably a protection somewhere in Wordpress preventing its file from being included into scripts outside of Wordpress folder. Probably some anti-hack stuff.

Comment: there is no protection including file somewhere. you should add correct path.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with cookies https://wordpress.org/support/topic/checking-wordpress-login-status-from-outside-the-blog

Answer (score 1):

If your script is outside the wordpress directory, you need to add the following lines to your wp-config.php before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

```
/** Set cookie path so we can access login from anywhere */
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
```

This is because by default, your login cookie is only accessible to your wordpress directory.